# Can a device create it's own MAC address using parts of other MAC addresses on your network?

Tags: mac, home-networking

I found that an unidentified device on my home network displays a MAC address that just happens to be made up of the last half of an iphone's MAC address (also on same network), and the first half of a netgear device (wifi signal extender). The device is listed as a netgear device, but i'm not sure what it is?

Is this just a mere coincidence? Or is this something normal? Or odd?

Comment: Normal. It's your iPhone when connected via the repeater.  It avoids address conflicts. It's covered in the manual.

Comment: See also https://community.netgear.com/t5/WiFi-Range-Extenders-Nighthawk/virtual-MAC-addresses/td-p/494762

Comment: PS  you should place your answer in the answer section so I can upvote it. ; )

Comment: done.  It seemed to short for an answer, but it is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Normal.

In your example, it's your iPhone when connected via the repeater. It avoids address conflicts. It's covered in the manual. It's called a Virtual Mac Address.

See also: https://community.netgear.com/t5/WiFi-Range-Extenders-Nighthawk/virtual-MAC-addresses/td-p/494762

Comment: Great! i'm relatively new here so i haven't gotten the ability to upvote yet, but as soon as I'm able to I will. In the meantime, you have my petsonal upvote and the checkmark for Yes, that's the answer I'm looking for.